# `stack ghci` incompatible ghc options on macOS

Tags: haskell-stack

I'm trying to setup Haskell environment on my macbook (high sierra). I'm using stack 1.6.3 x86_64 hpack-0.20.0 and creating new project with default template (resolver is lts-10.5). If I run stack ghci without changing anything, I get the following warning I can not deal with.

```
The following GHC options are incompatible with GHCi and have not been passed to it: -threaded
```

Any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: Is it just a warning? Does GHCi run after printing that, or does it fail to launch?

Comment: It's just a warning. GHCi works after it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is even a "warning," it's just informational. GHC and GHCi share a lot of the same options, so when Stack starts GHCi it just takes the GHC compiler options from `package.yaml` and passes them all as options to GHCi.

The default Stack template contains an executable that is compiled with the `-threaded` option (which you can see by looking in the `package.yaml` file that `stack new` generates). This isn't an option that is applicable to GHCi (it is a linker option that enables threading in the RTS, but [it seems that threading is always enabled in the REPL regardless](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/11615#comment:1)), so it's just letting you know that it doesn't have any effect. But it doesn't indicate a problem.

Comment: Is there a way to suppress this message when loading into ghci? I can't be the only one who doesn't like useless warnings.